# Update field based on values in other fields using search and update cursors

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, cursor, update, search

I'm a Python beginner, I'm doing a risk analysis with a point feature, and I'm trying to write a script that allow me to update a field (proximity) based on different numeric values within different fields.

Each field (`field_1`, `field_2`, `field_3`, `field_4`) has just one possible value ( respectively `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`) and in each row there is recorded only one of these different values.
Example: If in a row there's `1` in `field_1`  it's impossible to find other values in the other fields.

I would like to put everything in one field (proximity) to indicate the risk level.

I tried to run the following script to test only with `field_1`, but it's not updating, it's just printing `"Nothing for each row"`.

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("point", "proximity") as cursor: 
for row in cursor: 
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor("point", "field_1") as scursor:
        for row in scursor: 
            if row[0] == 1:
                cursor.updateRow(row)
        else: 
            print ("Nothing")
```

Comment: For now I have solved doing 4 different layer selection by attribute + calculate field for the new field, but I think there is something much simpler...

Comment: Nesting update and search cursors is usually unnecessary, but if it is required, so is not using conflicting variables. Unfortunately, you don't have enough code or verbiage to determine what it is that you want to do.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot showing you table and your expected output. I dont understand your description

Comment: The code that you have presented looks like it would give an indentation error on its second line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
import arcpy
fc = 'points1'
fields = ['Field1','Field2','Field3','Result']
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc,fields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[-1] = max(row[:-1])
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

You might need to change `max(row[:-1])`. For example if you can have `None` values in some field, it will fail. Then try `max([v for v in row[:-1] if v is not None])`

[image]